# Javascript --> for-loop through Array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have the following data structure against the background of a survey in Javascript.

```
quest_1: {
  quest: 'Question',
    answers: [
      {text: 'answer 1', active: false, multiple: false},
      {text: 'answer 2', active: false, multiple: false},
      {text: 'answer 3', active: false, multiple: false},
      {text: 'answer 4', active: false, multiple: false},
    ],
    choice: [],
},
...
```

The program manipulates this active-states in course of userEvents (click an answer).
For saving the current user-choice I have the following method with a for-loop through the data-structure above (answer-Array):

```
pushAnswer(answers, target){
    for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    console.log(answers[i].active);
    if(answers.active === true){
    target.push(answers.text);
   } else{
   console.log('error');
  }
 }
}
```

This method only runs after the user has take a choice, a `console.log` to the data-structure shows the active-status `true` after an answer was clicked (target parameter is another array for saving the answers (single- and multiple-choice)).

**My problem: The for-loop above only gives a false in every iteration.**

I tried several variants with declaration of variables with `let` inside the loop, but it doesn´t works. I can´t figure out where´s the problem, I can imagine, that the challenge are the objects in this array.

--edit--

**Thank you for your information, I tried to add the index in statement, but I can´t reach the active-status.**

*modified code:*

```
pushAnswer(answers, target){
  for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
   console.log(answers[i].active);
   console.log(answers[i]);
   if(answers[i].active == true){
   target.push(answers[i].text);
   } else{
    console.log('error');
   }
```

}
}

In the following picture you can see the data-structure in the `objects` inside `array` and inside the array.
With focus on the 3. object(Answer) the first console.log shows false, the Array shows true.
Why I can´t reach the active-state of these objects in my statement?

[image: console.log]

I hope anyone can give me a tip for approach.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing the array index in `answers.active` and `answers.text`. Replace with `answers[i].active` etc...

Comment: thank you for for your answer. I tried to change the statement and edited my question. Perhaps you can give check my console.log image. thanks in  advance.

Comment: I just ran your modified `pushAnswer` on an array of 4 questions with the 3rd being active. It worked fine. I assume you have an error in the surrounding code, e.g. by setting `active = true` only after calling `pushAnswer` (which would still lead to the console output you showed us).

Comment: thanks for your additional information, the problem was in the surrounding code...it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler approach would be to use `Array.filter` to remove items that you no longer want in your array:

```
pushAnswer(answers, target){
   const activeAnswers = answers.filter(answer => answer.active === true);
   target.push(...activeAnswers);
}
```

That could easily be a one-liner:

```
pushAnswer(answers, target){
   target.push(...answers.filter(({active}) => active));
}
```

I just broke it out so that it was more clear. If you don't have ES6 (looks like this is a class method so I assume you did):

```
pushAnswer(answers, target){
   var activeAnswers = answers.filter(function(answer) {
       return answer.active === true
   });
   target = target.concat(activeAnswers);
}
```

If you only want the `.text` property of the matching objects, you can add an additional `.map` operation to select only that property:

```
pushAnswer(answers, target){
   const activeText = answers.filter(({active}) => active)
                             .map(({text}) => text)
   target.push(...activeText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob for your answer, a smart way for solving this case, I tried the ES6 variant!

Comment: Hello Rob, because of my data structure I get back the right objects which contains an active = true as array. How can I include the statement, that the return of this filter set the object.text in the "result-array" ? (and not 'only' the relevant whole object). -thanks again for your support.

Comment: @Sash84 No problem, glad to help! I updated my answer to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sample = [{a:1, b:1}, {a:2, b:2}];
for(var index in sample){
  if(sample.hasOwnProperty(index){
    var obj = sample[index];
    console.log(obj.a + ' ' + obj.b);
  }
}
```

use this construct like a foreach

Comment: thank you for your answer. I edited my question with a new try of my for-loop statement and can´t figure out why the shown console.log can´t reach the active-state in this array.